# what is difference between sbt/scala-seed.g8 and scala/scala-seed.g8?

Tags: scala, sbt

The [sbt-hello](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html) uses `sbt new` command to quickly setup a project:

```
sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

However, I cannot find `sbt/scala-seed.g8` in [giter8-templates](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/wiki/giter8-templates).

what is difference between `sbt/scala-seed.g8` and `scala/scala-seed.g8`? Is it an alias?

Answer (score 2):

giter8 templates use github to create a project:

you can see the raw templates:

- for [scala/scala-seed.g8](https://github.com/scala/scala-seed.g8)
- for [sbt/scala-seed.g8](https://github.com/sbt/scala-seed.g8)

Answer (score 2):

[sbt/scala-seed.g8](https://github.com/sbt/scala-seed.g8) is a fork from [scala/scala-seed.g8](https://github.com/scala/scala-seed.g8).
Use the latter any way.